# Okhttp 3.x dynamically add/remove authenticator / interceptor

Tags: java, interceptor, okhttp, authenticator

Is it possible to add/remove Authenticators and/or Interceptors to an existing `Okhttp` instance? If yes, how?

Comment: Well, API is pretty explanatory: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#application-interceptors

It shows how to add an Interceptor during okhttp instance creation. But I cannot find a way to add it afterwards without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible.

However, you can create a builder from an existing client, and make changes to that.  This will share the dispatcher, connectionPool etc.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = client1.newBuilder();
clientBuilder.networkInterceptors().add(0, serviceInterceptor);
OkHttpClient client2 = clientBuilder.build();
```

There is an example for adjusting the timeout of a client in the javadoc https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html

Comment: Thing is I usually create okhttp as a single instance object through dependency injection, therefore it's not  possible to 'swap' the single instance with another one every time I add/remove an interceptor.

Comment: I guess OP is referring to "an existing Okhttp instance"

Comment: It may not work nicely for you, but it is the answer. Sorry it doesn't suit